# Unable to display responses of type "application/octet-stream"

Tags: c++, http, download

```
*response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << success.length();
*response << "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream";
*response << "\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" << filename << '"';
*response << "\r\n\r\n" << success;
```

I set the response header like this to let the browser to download the result from the server rather than to show the result directly. But it can't show the download box as expected, and the browser shows that "Unable to display responses of type "application/octet-stream"".

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the file type? What happens if you leave out Content-Type and Content-Disposition?

Comment: the file type can be .txt or .csv or .json , if I leave out Content-Type and Content-Disposition the result will return to the client but nothing shows in the browser

Comment: Does "success" happen to contain non-ASCII characters? (If that was the case, and the encoding was UTF-8, that might result in an incorrect content length). - Thinking of it, does "curl" handle the file correctly (with -v)?